# Nested JTabbedPane formatting issues

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtabbedpane

I have a `JTabbedPane` that looks like the image below:

[image]

The table with horizontal tabs is just a simple `JTabbedPane`, the vertical tabs are `JTabbedPane`s with tab placement set to `JTabbedPane.LEFT`. They are made vertical with the code in this article:
http://www.jroller.com/santhosh/date/20050617#adobe_like_tabbedpane_in_swing

Each of the tabs on the left side contains a `JTabbedPane` that has horizontal tabs.

I am looking to achieve two things but am having some trouble with them:

1) I want to get rid of the border that's around the area where the horizontal tabs are. I noticed that this border only shows up when I paint the inner tabbedPane as a component of the outer one, if I paint it by itself the border doesn't show up.

2) I want to make the vertical tabs align with the content table, rather than with the imaginary boundary that encloses the inner *tabbedPane*. I also am trying to get it to align better so there is no small spaces like the little space below the "Label" tab.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), no idea

Comment: The only way I can see you getting this to work is to provide your UI delegate, which in of itself, is not a small feat...